# Populate multiple textview list with data from sqlite3

Tags: android

I'm working on a amobile app using a listview. 
My goal is to select data from an SQLite database and display it like

```
Halo3    9.6/10
Call of Duty 5.0/10
```

My database has the ID,Game_name and Game_score which I select.

Right now what is being displayed in my app is this

```
halo 3
9.6/10
Call of Duty
5/10
```

And I know exactly why this is happening looking at this code.

Database Helper Class

```
        public List<String> allDetails(String num) {
                List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c;



try{

    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT INS,NUM FROM " + TB_numbers + " WHERE ID  = '"+ num + "'",null);

    if (c == null) return null;

        String ins,dnum;
             ins="";dnum="";
        String[] data=null;
        c.moveToFirst();
    do{
        ins = c.getString(0);
        details.add(ins);
        dnum=c.getString(1);
        details.add(dnum);


    }while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();


    } catch(
        Exception e
        )

{
    Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
}

            return details;
        }
```

When i pass in "num" ,I am adding both the name of the game and the rating to the List. I would like advice on how I could return the game name and score separately. I am not aware of being able to return two list at once, and even if I could...I would think I will get issues when populating my listview from two list array. 
So my question more specifically is, how do I populate two custom textviews with data from two different columns in from my database.

Comment: What you can do is use a HashMap storing Entries. Thus you can return two results. And use custom adapter for the list view. (Develop one extending BaseAdapter, is pretty easy)

Comment: @Joaquin I know how do to a custom adapter for a list view but could you expound on HAshMap storing entries?

Comment: Maps are data structures intended to save a collection of entries. Each entry has a key and a value. And that's all. Instead of having a list of strings you have a map of entries, each one containing a key (in order to identify the entry) and a value (the data associated to this key). The key and the value can be of any type. They are generic collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a Model class. For example:

```
public class Rating { 
    public final String name; 
    public final String rating;

    Rating(String name, String rating) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

Instead of returning a `List <String>` return a `List <Rating>`.

Populate your ratings like this.

```
ratings.add(new Rating(ins, dnum));
```

To use your name and rating:

```
Rating someRating = ratings.get(index);

Log.v("TAG", "The name: " + someRating.name + " rating: " + someRating.rating);
```

In a real world scenario you should probably use private fields. But public are better for simplicity.

Comment: Also, trying out ORM like ORMLite would reduce a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: What would your add method look like? Is it possible to not need to write one by just extending to a class?

Comment: @Liberace .add is the standard method for List.